# NuGet: Run C# Code on Install/Update/Uninstall

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm just getting to grips with nuget after avoiding it for a while. I was wondering if it was possible to run some C# code when you install, update or uninstall a nuget package?

For example I'd like to run a set of database changes which are within a .sql file within my package once the package is installed.

I'd appreciate if someone could let me know if this is possible and if so point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: A .cs file. I just need to a way to run custom code once the package is installed without the user having to execute the SQL file manually against their database. I've re-worded my question so this makes a little more sense. However I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: Thing is: a script needs an Interpreter C# is no Scripting-Language.

Comment: Does it have to be C#? Nuget does support running powershell scripts, and I'm sure it's possible to talk to SQL from powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use powershell so you can write some c# code and run please [check link](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Running_PowerShell_Scripts_During_Package_Installation_and_Removal)

Well instead of copy paste not my own job here is link to [real example](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx)

Comment: It would be best if you added examples from the link here. It's easier for the OP to get his answer, and also allows the answer to stand on it's own even if the link breaks down the road.

Comment: @DaveZych okey will do that :) I never thought about it since some times for me usefull link is better than example but i got it :)

Comment: @DaveZych btw can you tell me what OP means ?

Comment: Original Poster. The person that asked the question.

Comment: Because i tried to select words but did not know that it Original Poster.

Comment: Also i just added one more link as i think no needs to copy paste better would be to add link to original post.

Comment: Thanks that's pretty neat. This looks like exactly what I'm after.